# Unable to retrieve a single item when through HTTPRequest with Django Rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I follow the instructions on Django Restframework tutorial [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) and has configured everything after it, but somehow, I can't use id to retrieve the json for a single item.

I expect to get a json representation of a single item when i request localhost:8080/items/[index], but instead of getting the item with the corresponding index I would get json representation of every items in I have.
My views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def item_list(request):
"""
List and create items
"""
    if request.method == 'GET':
        items = Item.objects.all()
        serializer = ItemSerializer(items, many=True)

        return Response({'data': serializer.data })

@api_view(['GET'])
def item_detail(request, pk):
"""
Retrieve an item
"""
    try:
        item = Item.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Item.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = ItemSerializer(item)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

My urls.py in item module

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'$', views.item_list),
    url(r'^items/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.item_detail),
]
```

My urls.py in app module

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('menu.urls')),
]
```

---

Edit: Thanks for the reply but it I think I have found a fix. It seems like by putting 'url(r'$', views.item_list)' in front all links will reroute to item_list(). The easy fix is just put it behind 'url(r'^items/(?P[0-9]+)/$', views.item_detail)'

Comment: Can you add your `urls.py`?

Comment: You do not need those if statements because the `@api_view(['GET'])` makes sure it is a GET request

Comment: My urls.py setting is exactly the same as in the tutorials I linked above, that's why I didn't put them.
But here it is:

Comment: you should still put it in your question. i believe all you requests are going to `item_list `

Comment: What is the current response you got?

Answer (score 0):

switch the url paths in your url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^items/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.item_detail),
    url(r'^$', views.item_list),
]
```

and include like

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('menu.urls')),
]
```